# Weird checkbox behaviour in acceptance testing using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

When I submit a form with checkboxes all blank via browser, the `coach_ids=>[""]` and `recruit_board_ids"=>[""]` are blank and its fine.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"66vEbZPQ9aq/l1hYQbthRyjrYGtnrRQgLygFmgE8ZSA=", "recruit"=>{"coach_ids"=>[""], "recruit_board_ids"=>[""]}
```

But when I do the same in acceptance test using capybara, edge version from github, those checkboxes aren't blank. It contains some weird escaped chars.
The params hash is trimmed down to make it clear.

```
params::{"utf8"=>"✓", "recruit"=>{"coach_ids"=>["[\"\"]"], "recruit_board_ids"=>["[\"\"]"]}
```

Couldn't figure out whats wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem in rack-test that hasn't been fixed in an official build yet.  See https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/issues/12 and https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/288/